How to make in PGFPlots the 3D box having 0.4pt width lines?
I have the problem with setting layers in PGFPlots. I would like to put the external box lines on every other elements (plot lines, grid, ticks). The same question was asked here: PGFPLOTS 3d box line for Z axis not being drawn. But there is no answer.
Also all axis lines should have round caps - to not leave gaps by their connections.

Code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.7,
    every axis plot/.append style={line join=round},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines={%
        circle,
        magnification=15,
        size=2cm,
        connect spies,
        every spy in node/.style={fill=white,draw},
        every spy on node/.style={draw},
    }
]
\begin{axis}[%
    width=60mm,
    height=60mm,
    scale only axis,
    zmin=0.1,
    zmax=0.5,
    tick align=inside,
    max space between ticks=25mm,
    view={215}{30},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    zmajorgrids
]

\addplot3 [surf,shader=flat corner,mesh/rows=3] table [row sep=crcr,point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
x   y   z   c\\
6.4  9  0.32    0.32\\
6.4 10  0.15    0.25\\
6.4 11  0.19    0.19\\
7.0  9  0.35    0.35\\
7.0 10  0.28    0.28\\
7.0 11  0.23    0.23\\
7.6  9  0.37    0.37\\
7.6 10  0.31    0.31\\
7.6 11  0.25    0.25\\
};

\coordinate (pt1) at (axis cs:6.4,9,0.32);
\spy on (pt1) in node at (4.5cm,2cm);
\coordinate (pt2) at (axis cs:6.4,9,0.40);
\spy on (pt2) in node at (4.5cm,5cm);
\coordinate (pt3) at (axis cs:7.6,11,0.5);
\spy on (pt3) in node at (1.5cm,3cm);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you want that fine control, you might be interested in reproducing the graphic with plain tikz. In general, tikz was designed for 2D drawings, and has these sorts of limitations in 3D - you have to layer things on top of one another so it looks good enough.

Unrelated, but max space between ticks is a number without unit.

I guess you are looking for that:
% ADDED ============================
axis line style={red, line cap=round},
grid style={blue, line cap=round},
% ================================


\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.7,
    every axis plot/.append style={line join=round},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines={%
        circle,
        magnification=15,
        size=2cm,
        connect spies,
        every spy in node/.style={fill=white,draw},
        every spy on node/.style={draw},
    }
]
\begin{axis}[%
    width=60mm,
    height=60mm,
    scale only axis,
    zmin=0.1,
    zmax=0.5,
    tick align=inside,
    max space between ticks=25mm,
    view={215}{30},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    zmajorgrids,
% ADDED ============================
axis line style={red, line cap=round},
grid style={blue, line cap=round},
% ================================
]

\addplot3 [surf,shader=flat corner,mesh/rows=3] table [row sep=crcr,point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
x   y   z   c\\
6.4  9  0.32    0.32\\
6.4 10  0.15    0.25\\
6.4 11  0.19    0.19\\
7.0  9  0.35    0.35\\
7.0 10  0.28    0.28\\
7.0 11  0.23    0.23\\
7.6  9  0.37    0.37\\
7.6 10  0.31    0.31\\
7.6 11  0.25    0.25\\
};

\coordinate (pt1) at (axis cs:6.4,9,0.32);
\spy on (pt1) in node at (4.5cm,2cm);
\coordinate (pt2) at (axis cs:6.4,9,0.40);
\spy on (pt2) in node at (4.5cm,5cm);
\coordinate (pt3) at (axis cs:7.6,11,0.5);
\spy on (pt3) in node at (1.5cm,3cm);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If a grid is painted similarly to box lines (both in black) then it is sufficient. I prefer original black box and gray grid. For me the most important is to hide the plot corner behind the vertical axis line. Also the tick that is visible should be hidden behind the line and the one that is hidden should be visible.
